# Matching words starting and ending with same vowel letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to come up with a regex to match words starting and ending with same vowel. My question is, is this an elegant all-encompassing solution or am i missing something? So far this is what I have come up after a quick brainstroming. My preferred environment is javascript/python without special libraries etc. Thanks for helpful suggestions.

- soln. 1)  `re = /(^[aeiou])\w+\1/i;`
- soln. 2)  `re = /(^[aeiou])[a-zA-Z]+\1/i;`
- `console.log(re.test("abcda"));  //true`
- `console.log(re.test("abcdo"));  //false`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Words can be matched using a word boundary `\b`:

```
var re = /\b([aeiou])[a-z]+\1\b/i;
```

The [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iG7bS0/1)

The regex matches:

- `\b` - leading word boundary (because the pattern after it matches a word character)
- `([aeiou])` - Group 1 capturing a vowel from the specified range
- `[a-z]+` - one or more letters (both upper- and lowercase since the `/i` modifier is used)
- `\1` -  backreference to the vowel captured with the first group
- `\b` - trailing word boundary

Comment: Stribizew:  Wow, Thanks for a really quick answer! thumbs up! I was debating about whether or not to use word boundary \b as i didnt know if they would work universally. Thanks!

Comment: Well,  `\b` should work with English words. With Russian, Bulgarian, etc. there will be a problem :(

Comment: yes thats what I was worried about but i guess i will stick with english words for now, got to think of others soon :) :(